# how to pass image file from database to html in django project

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, forms

I tried many solution to solve it. But I can't fix and resolve. I can't able to pass the image file of my users to my html page. But I can able to access and pass all elements from database of a specific user. When I try to access the Image file of a user, it just returns a file path of the image. Please help me to resolve it.

**models.py**

```
class registration(models.Model):


    First_Name =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Phone_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    Email_id = models.EmailField()
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Conform_Password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Register_No = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="Profile")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.First_Name
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request, *args, **kwargs):

 if request.method == 'POST':
     user_Name=int(request.POST["stu_uname"])
     pass_word=request.POST["stu_pwd"]

     get_user_name = registration.objects.filter(Register_No = user_Name).exists()
     if get_user_name is True:
         check_pwd = registration.objects.values('Password').filter(Register_No = user_Name)
         for check in check_pwd:
             pwd = check['Password']
                     if pwd == pass_word:
             user_objects = get_objects(user_Name)
             return render(request, "stu_profile.html", {'userObj': user_objects})
         else:
             return HttpResponse("<h1> Password is incorrect</h1>")
     else:
         return HttpResponse("<h1> User name is incorrect </h1>")
 return redirect('student')
def get_objects(name):

 check_objects = registration.objects.values().filter(Register_No = name)
 for check in check_objects:
     values = check   
 return values
```

**HTML PAGE**

```
    <div class="pro_pic">

      <img src = "{{userObj.profile_pic}}"> #this image doesn't render. 

      <div>
        <p> {{userObj.First_Name}} {{userObj.Last_name}} </p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

**Settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Pictures/') 
MEDIA_URL = '/Pictures/'
```

Comment: 1) Even if you don't want to use `objects.get` you can do `objects.filter(...)[:1]` to get an instance instead of list - this will allow you to get rid of that obscure for-loop. 2) get the image URL from rendered HTML and try to open it directly - what the response status/error message?

Comment: Hey bro, There is no error messages. I already said, I can able to access everything from the database, But the ImageField returns the file path of the image where it stored.

Comment: Picture is main media_root folder, Inside that folder my models.py creates an another folder cause of my instructions. So when I accessing the ImageField I get the path of the image like ("Pictures/Profile/something.jpg") this.

Comment: Please change your template code as @arjun suggested (`...profile_pic.url`), get the full URL from rendered page, copy this URL and open it in another browser tab. Please add this URL (not path) and the response status to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

**HTML PAGE**

```
{% load static %} 
{% static "img" as baseUrl %}

<div class="pro_pic">

      <img src = "{{userObj.profile_pic.url}}"> #this image doesn't render. 

      <div>
        <p> {{userObj.First_Name}} {{userObj.Last_name}} </p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

And `{% static "< your image folder name in static folder > as baseurl" %}`